# ASP.NET Namespace Control for Multiple data storage and easy .ToJSON()

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, list, hashtable

I need to store a List or Hashtable or something that looks like this:

```
Element[542]["Title"] = "Some Title";
Element[542]["Html"] = "some Value";
Element[542]["CSS"] = "some class css";
Element[542]["SomethingElse"] = something else goes in here.

Element[621]["Title"] = "Title for 621";
Element[621]["Html"] = "Some Html value for 621";
Element[621]["CSS"] = "Some CSS Class";
Element[621]["SomethingElse"] = "something else goes in here."
```

How can I create a list like this?  Would be great if I can than convert it to json based on the value of the number, for example, 621 would be the value, so it would grab only those of that number and output it in a JSON variable, something like this:

```
AddMoreJsonToThisVariable.621 = {

    Title : "Title for 621",
    Html : "Some Html value for 621",
    CSS :  "Some CSS Class",
    SomethingElse : "something else goes in here."
}
```

Is there anything in ASP.NET that can be used to generate lists like this?  Or a way to do this of some sort?  Can a Hashtable be inserted into the 2nd parameter of another Hashtable?  Could that work?

Comment: Generally we don't use HashTable. We use the generic List or Dictionary classes. And [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) is the widely used library for converting those to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create a class.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    public string Html {get;set;}
    public string CSS {get;set;}
    public string SomethingElse {get;set;}
}

//Then create a dictionary.
Dictionary<int, MyClass> MyDictionary=new Dictionary<int, MyClass)();
// create an some instance of MyClass
MyClass MyClassInstance=new MyClass(){Id=621, Title="A Title", Html="Some Html", CSS= "Some CSS", SomethingElse="Something else goes here"};
//add it to your dictionary
MyDictionary.Add(MyClassInstance.Id, MyClassInstance);
//serialize it to JSON with Json.Net
string somejson= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyDictionary);
```

If you want to sort it when you output it use OrderBy with a lambda expression.

```
foreach(KeyValuePair<string, MyClass> kvp in MyDictionary.OrderBy(x => x.Key)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key is: " + kvp.Key + " and Html is: " + kvp.Value.Html);
}
```

I assumed a dictionary is what you want. If not, then figure out what [collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.generic.aspx) to use.

Comment: I already have a class.  That is how I am getting the data, but I need to switch it to a JSon variable formatted the the ID first.

Comment: Thanks, this looks exactly like what I need!!  As long as the Dictionary items are sorted by IDs first (what will get put into the first parameter)!

Comment: Also, curious do I have to create a class, or can something else go in there besides a class?  Says Value Collection in the docs, but not sure what that actually means....

Comment: You can put a struct or a primitive type in there. The dictionary is inherently not sorted. But when you access it, you can sort it. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Sorting is not important at all.  I just need to access the ID in Javascript and have it output all of the properties for that ID, in JSON.  But the ID is not always going to be the same, so it needs to load up all of the possible IDs and will have the same properties attached to these IDs.